# How to access neo4j browser from web application built on React+Redux

Tags: reactjs, iframe, neo4j, redux

We are trying to access **Neo4j Browser** screen from our web application, which is developed using React+Reduct framework. We tried to access Neo4j using simple iframe, unfortunately we are getting black page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have something in your browser console ?

Comment: Yes, if I access neo4j browser directly in any browser it works fine, i can see the graph.

Comment: No I mean the web console of your browser. For chrome, just push F12